# In spring boot which location we are saving a file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to save a file in spring boot and i can access it in production build also. So where i can store that file?

What is code for getting path , Now i am creating file in pom.xml file location

Comment: Access by what?

Comment: @meriton for jasper report i am temporary saving pdf , that file i need to read

Comment: It's unclear what you want. 1. Is the file already present during build (i.e. it should be included in your resources)? 2. Do you need to *write* to the file as well?

Answer (score -1):

You can define your destination yourself:

**One possible option:**

```
        FileOutputStream out;
        String filePath = "your destination";
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
            out.write(someFile.getBytes());
            out.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And later access it by path

Comment: That's i done, but in production it's not getting that file, when take build we can get that file?

Comment: You can create Custom class in which as attribute will be saved multipartfile. When you need to retrieve a file, you can do it by simple getter

Comment: Don't suggest code that is not even correct - you should use try-with-resource or a modern Files API that can save bytes without a stream...

Answer (score -1):

You can store a file anywhere in Spring Boot like the previous answer indicated.
However to make it easily accessible in production, it is recommended to save it in the src/main/resources folder since that will copy it into the target folder after the build is completed and you can access it just by mentioning it's relative path in your code, rather than using it's entire file path.

Comment: This is a bad idea without context - a file that is uploaded by a client absolutely does not belong in src/main/resources.